# 301 Redirects from ColdFusion to PHP in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I created a new (PHP) website and need to 301 redirect all of the old (ColdFusion) pages. Both sites are on the same CentOS server.

Here's one example rule that I have in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /products.cfm http://norrisealwellmark.com/products/
</IfModule>
```

The result of this redirect is **http://norrisealwellmark.com/products.cfm**

How do I prevent the **.cfm** from appending to the destination URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect` directive:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products\.cfm$ http://norrisealwellmark.com/products/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache while testing this change.